# Redução de códigos e declaração de variáveis

Tags: javascript, jquery, declaração-de-variável, owl-carousel

Bom dia. Tenho 8 variáveis diferentes com as mesmas funções.

No entanto, as funções atribuídas pas essas variáveis, são iguais.

Sinto que estou sendo repetitivo no código.

Existe alguma forma de declara-las todas de uma unica vez e a função ser escrita apenas uma vez, porém, equivalente para todas as 8 Variáveis?

```js
<script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
         
           var owl = $("#owl-demo");
         
           owl.owlCarousel({

               [700, 7],
               [1000, 8],
               [1200, 8],
               [1400, 8],
               [1600, 8]
             ],
             
         
           });
         
         var owl = $("#owl-demo2");
         
           owl.owlCarousel({
     
             
               [600, 5],
               [700, 7],
               [1000, 8],
               [1200, 8],
               [1400, 8],
               [1600, 8]
             ],
             
         
           });
           var owl = $("#owl-demo3");
         
           owl.owlCarousel({
       
      
               [700, 7],
               [1000, 8],
               [1200, 8],
               [1400, 8],
               [1600, 8]
             ],
             
         
           });
         
           var owl = $("#owl-demo4");
         
           owl.owlCarousel({
         
          
           
               [1400, 8],
               [1600, 8]
             ],
             
         
           });
         
         
           var owl = $("#owl-demo5");
         
           owl.owlCarousel({
         
   
  
               [1200, 8],
               [1400, 8],
               [1600, 8]
             ],
             
         
           });
         
         
           var owl = $("#owl-demo6");
         
           owl.owlCarousel({
         
      
    
               [1600, 8]
             ],
             
         
           });
         
         
           var owl = $("#owl-demo7");
         
           owl.owlCarousel({
  
             

           });
         
         
           var owl = $("#owl-demo8");
         
           owl.owlCarousel({


               [1200, 8],
               [1400, 8],
               [1600, 8]
             ],
             
         
           });
         
           var owl = $("#owl-demo9");
         
           owl.owlCarousel({
    
               [450, 4],
               [600, 5],
               [700, 7],
               [1000, 8],
               [1200, 8],
               [1400, 8],
               [1600, 8]
             ],
             
         
           });
         
         
         });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sim, com um loop. Observação: talvez precise criar uma lista para representar os objetos com os números (ainda não faço ideia do que seria um "owlCarousel" e "owl").

Nesse código eu não crio uma variável para cada `#owl-demo`, eu apenas guardo em um objeto `Array` para depois ser usado.

Observação: há erro de digito no código, pois em um construtor de objeto não dá para declarar propriedades sem nome, ou há não ser que você esteja no JavaScript da próxima geração.

```
var owlsData = [

    [[700, 7],
    [1000, 8],
    [1200, 8],
    [1400, 8],
    [1600, 8]],

    [[1400, 8],
    [1600, 8]],

    [[1200, 8],
    [1400, 8],
    [1600, 8]],

    [[1600, 8]],

    [[1200, 8],
    [1400, 8],
    [1600, 8]],

    [[450, 4],
    [600, 5],
    [700, 7],
    [1000, 8],
    [1200, 8],
    [1400, 8],
    [1600, 8]]

];

for (var i = 1, o, owls = [];
    i++ <= 9 && owls.push(o = $("#owl-demo" + (i === 1 ? "" : i)));)
    o.owlCarousel(owlsData[i - 1]);
```

Agora você pode acessar cada elemento em `owls`.